# How can use mysql like: SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `field`.length > 20

Tags: mysql

How can I find out how long the value of a column is. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `field`.length > 20
```

I know that this statement is wrong. I just don't know how to phrase it. I can't seem to find any documentation on the matter.

So I need to select all rows from a table that the phone field has more than 20 characters.

I imported a file and my customer merged 2 phones numbers in 1 fields, so I need to get all thoses affected rows to fix them.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`length()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length) function to determine how many characters the field has in it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE length(`field`) > 20
```

If you think you will have whitespace, then you can combine it with [`TRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_trim):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE length(trim(`field`)) > 20
```

Comment: thanks ill accept your answer in 10 mins.. wont let me just yet. thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE LENGTH(field) > 20
```

Check the docs in cases like this; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want the length of the field in bytes (ascii characters), you can use the [LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length) function, and if you want to be "multi byte safe" for international character sets like UTF-8, you can use [CHAR_LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) which counts actual characters.

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(`field`) > 20
```

Answer (score 0):

use lenght():

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE LENGTH(field) > 20
```